# Why radio button in HTML in special division doesn't works?

Tags: html, css

I have two radio buttons which show/hide `div`s oh my website. The first radio button controls the visibility of a `div`. In this `div` I have another radio button which shows/hides another `div`. The first radio button works, but when I click on the second one nothing happens.

This is an example of my HTML and CSS code :

HTML :

```
<body>


    <label for="a">B</label><input type="radio" id="a" name="a" value="1">

    <div id="B">

        <p>Div B</p>
        <label for="c">D</label><input type="radio" id="c" name="c" value="1">

    </div>

    <div id="D">

        <p>Div D</p>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS :

```
#B
{
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;

    display: none;
}

#D
{
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;

    display: none;
}

#a:checked ~ #B
{
    display: block;
}

#c:checked ~ #D
{
    display: block;
}
```

I don't understand why the second button does nothing.
Is there a solution without using JS?

Thank you,

Comment: You are using ["sibling selectors"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) in your CSS, but `#c` is not a sibling of `#D`.

Comment: Thank you for this links, now I understand why it doesn't works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @showdev said, `#c` is not a sibling of `#D` so sibling selectors won't works in that case.

If you wants this to work with only CSS you have to change your structure or do this with javascript.

**EDIT** : I made it works with only CSS and HTML arrangement :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nabn4n80/7/)

**HTML :**

```
<body>
    <label for="a">B</label><input type="radio" id="a" name="a" value="1">
    <div id="B">
        <p>Div B</p>
    </div>
    <label for="c">D</label><input type="radio" id="c" name="c" value="1">
    <div id="D">
      <p>Div D</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS that change :**

```
#a:checked ~ #B
{
    display: block;
}
#c:checked ~ #D 
{
    display: block;
}
label:nth-of-type(2), input:nth-of-type(2) { display: none; clear: both;}

#a:checked ~ label:nth-of-type(2), #a:checked ~ input:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to see if i will use JS, or if I can change my structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript, unless you need a restricted solution that doesn't involves js at all.. You can easily solve your problem with an onClick function, like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="a" value="1" onclick="somefunctionA()">
<label for="c">D</label><input type="radio" id="c" name="c" value="1" onclick="somefunctionB()">
<script>
    function somefunctionA(){
        //do something!
    }

    function somefunctionB(){
        //do something!
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too.